# One to Many Relation In Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

I have 2 Tables

1. Users
2. Messages

**And the Structure of Tables:**

Users:

[image]

Messages:

[image]

Now see there are number of users in **Users Table** and their messages are stored in **Messages table** identifying by `fk_user_Id`.

How can I make **One-To-Many** Relationship between these two tables or create this SQL Schema using **Doctrine**/Annotations?

Comment: It's really not hard. Just read the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: @Cyprian Can you answer its solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common case and i think you can easily find such examples if you would have searched.

You may refer this [example](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html)

Your two entity files `User.php` and `Message.php` will look something like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Message", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $messages;
}
```

Message entity will look like this

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="messages")
     */
    class Message
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $messageDescription;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="messages")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked for me. Can you also refer me how to perform Insertion operations ?

Comment: The example link that i have given in the answer step by step guide to almost all the basic operations. Even the official symfony documentation is enough to get you through such easy tasks